# cannot retrieve data from Header param using fastapi

Tags: python, backend, fastapi

I am learing how to use FastAPI and testng a couple of things before I start building my new API with it.

But I just can't make the Headers param to work.

this is what my simple test function looks like:

```
@app.get('/hello')
def testing_header(x_token: Annotated[str, Header()] = None):
    return {'header': x_token}
```

it's pretty straight forward I just want to return the value of the header to make sure it is working, but it just returns None / null.

I followed literally what is written on the fastAPi documentation and it does not work still.

I tried multiple different forms of writing it, not using the Annotated, or just passing like:

```
def testing_header(x_token: str = Header():
```

or even

```
def testing_header(x_token: str = Header(defalt=None)):
```

and nothing works. Can anyone help me understand why doesn't it retrieve the value of the header param.

Also worth mentioning that I tested the endpoint both using insomnia and postman

Comment: Using `Annotated` only works with FastAPI 0.95+, so which version of FastAPI are you using? What does the header you're sending look like?

Comment: I am using 0.95

my header looks like x_token : fhsefhef. Also I defined the header on insomnia using the headers tab. There is no way the issue is with the header being sent

Comment: If you're using `x_token` in your parameter name, FastAPI expects the header to be named `X-Token`, not `x_token`. It's the common naming scheme for HTTP headers, but since Python can't declare a variable as named `X-Token` directly, headers are mapped from `-` to `_`. If you _really_ want to use underscores (you shouldn't, people expect headers to named as `X-Token` and some proxies/server software doesn't allow underscores), you can give `convert_underscores=False` to `Header()`.